# matrix - operator + overloading in a method

Tags: python, matrix, methods, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a problem with understanding (?) how the overload operator in methods works, can someone help me and show me how I can, for example, overload the method below (i.e. operator +)

```
 def add(mat1, mat2):
        if mat1.height != mat2.height or mat1.width != mat2.width:
            print("The matrices are not the same size!")
            return

        rows = []
        for i in range(len(mat1.data)):
            row = []
            for j in range(len(mat1.data[0])):
                row.append(mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j])

            rows.append(tuple(row))
        return MyMatrix(tuple(rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a `+`-operator for a custom type (in your case the class `MyMatrix`) you just have to implement it as a method of the corresponding class (`MyMatrix`) and use the corresponding names for said method. For the `+` operator this name is `__add__`, (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types))

So in your case you'd have to write

```
class MyMatrix:
   def __add__(self, mat2):
          mat1 = self
          if mat1.height != mat2.height or mat1.width != mat2.width:
              print("The matrices are not the same size!")
              return
  
          rows = []
          for i in range(len(mat1.data)):
              row = []
              for j in range(len(mat1.data[0])):
                  row.append(mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j])

              rows.append(tuple(row))
          return MyMatrix(tuple(rows))
```